# Terms and condtions

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1

Does Magento keep a record when customers accept the terms and conditions?

If yes where would I be able to find that information?

If no is there a there a way to keep track of who is accepting the terms and conditions?

I know the customer has to agree before he or she can place an order. This is purely for legal reasons. I am on version 1.9 of the community edition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No record is kept no, but as you note the fact that an order has been placed means the customer must have agreed.  With only one possibility, keeping a record would be rather pointless.